# Jetpack post types Portfolio or Testimonials support for custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, plugin-jetpack

Is there a way to add custom fields support for Jetpack’s custom post types testimonials?
I’ve added the post type manually on functions.php and also in Jetpack’s own panel but I cannot figure out how to add support for custom fields.

I’ve searched all over the web for the answer but so far I cannot find anything about it and I’m sure it should be a simple line of code.

I would hate to have to write code to add a custom post type when Jetpack already provide that.